# The problem with geolocation, once gave the result, all the others timeout

Tags: node.js, google-maps

I installed https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js

I connect `import maps from '@google/maps';`

I create a client:

```
const googleMapsClient = maps.createClient({
    key: 'api key',
});
```

I want to get latitude and longitude:

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    googleMapsClient.geocode({
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA'
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(res.json.results);
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: res.json.results
            });
        }
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            err: err
        });
    });
    ...
```

My problem is that the first time he gave information

```
[ { address_components:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ],
    formatted_address: '1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA',
    geometry:
     { location: [Object],
       location_type: 'ROOFTOP',
       viewport: [Object] },
    place_id: 'ChIJhhRjJ-5j4ARKFsUSrwhY',
    plus_code:
     { compound_code: 'CWC8+JH Mountain View, California, United States',
       global_code: '849VCWC8+JH' },
    types: [ 'street_address' ] } ]
```

All the next time he gives me

```
timeout
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have billing account enabled for your API key?

Comment: No, I did everything and set a quota of 100. Everything works

Comment: did you find out solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If billing is not enabled on your project, your Maps Platform APIs will be limited to 1 request per day. You can get higher quota by enabling billing on your project.

[Google Maps Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#limit_1)